# Separate expression $c(x + y)^2 e^{yz}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bayesian

Considering the following expression, with $x, y, z, c \in \mathbb{R}$, is such expression separable into $f(x, y, z) = g(x, z)h(y, z)$?

$c(x + y)^2 e^{yz}$

If not, why isn't it separable?

**Note**:

- $c$ is a constant, but I'm not sure if I can remove it, though.

---

**Adding context**: the original question concerns proving whether or not a given expression represents the function of probability distribution of two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, conditioned to $Z$ -- $f(x, y \mid z)$.

This may also be written as $\mathbb{P} \models X \bot Y \mid Z$.

---

Here's what I've been able to do so far:

$c(x + y)^2 e^{yz} = $

$ = c[x^2 + 2xy + y^2]e^{yz} = $

$ = [x^2 + 2xy]ce^{yz} + cy^2 e^{yz}$

Using $t = xy$:

$c\left[x^2 + 2t\right] e^{\left(\frac{tz}{x}\right)} + c\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)^2 e^{\left(\frac{tz}{x}\right)}$

From here I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: Could you define what "seperable" means? Dies it mean it can be expressed as a sum of terms, each term in different variables [none of $x,y,z$ in both terms]? Also if $c$ is a constant you may as well drop it from the question.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for your reply; I've tried to add context to my question, so that it may clarify what I'm trying to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally we assume $c \ne 0$, otherwise the zero map is clearly seperable. Suppose $c(x+y)^2 e^{yz}=g(x,z)h(y,z).$ Define $k(y,z)=h(y,z)/[c e^{yz}].$ This is OK since $e^{yz}>0$ for all $y,z$. Then we have
$$[1]\ \ (x+y)^2=g(x,z)k(y,z).$$ But this is not possible since the mixed partials $\partial^2/\partial x \partial y$ of the two sides are now $2$ for the left side and $0$ for the right side.

Note that [1] can also be shown impossible without partials: Let $z$ be constant and put $u(x)=g(x,z)$ and $v(y)=k(y,z).$ Then [1] becomes
$$(x+y)^2=u(x)v(y).$$ The zero set of the left side is the line $y=-x$, whereas if the zero sets of $u,v$ are $A,B$ respectively, the zero set of the right side is $A \times B$, and no matter what the sets $A,B$ are one cannot express the line $y=-x$ as the cartesian product $A \times B.$

Comment: Two questions: why having $2 = 0$ in the partials approach is enough to determine the statement? why one cannot express $A \times B$ with $y = -x$?

Comment: @Rubens -- In the partials approach, the mixed partials must be equal *if* the functions $g,h$ are assumed to have continuous second derivatives. And $y=-x$ is not $A \times B$, since for example $y=-x$ contains the point $(0,0)$, and if $A \times B$ also contained $(0,0)$ it would contain the entire $x$ and $y$ axes, which the line $y=-x$ doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $x=-y$ then $f(x,y,z) = 0$.

Pick your value of $x$, then either $g(x,z)$ or $h(y,z)$ is zero (or both).

Let's say without loss of generality that $g(x,z) = 0$.

This implies that $f(x,y,z)=0$ for all $y,z$ which is clearly false from the definition of $f$.