# Independent random variables considering expression

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, bayesian

Having $x, y, z, c \in \mathbb{R}$, is it valid to say:

$c \propto g(x, z) h(y, z)$

The context here is to say whether or not the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent given the value of $Z$.

The above statement is one of the series of four statements that validates $P \models X \bot Y \mid Z$, having $c$ as the expression.

For example, if I had $cxyz$ as the expression, $cxyz \propto g(x, z) h(y, z)$ is valid, since I'm able to do $g(x, z) = cxz;\ h(y, z) = cyz$. I'm not sure if I can say $g(x, z) = c;\ h(y, z) = c$, though.

Is it valid?

Comment: The delay between the (only) answer being posted and it being accepted is 1 min. Is this reasonable?

Comment: @Did I'm not sure about here; it's valid on stackoverflow. I guess the answer down here is valid, since I've understood what is being disposed. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330668/separate-expression-cx-y2-eyz), though, I have two answers, but I'm not able to say which one is the right one. It'd be very helpful if someone voted on the right, so that I could be guided to the answer. I've also unmarked this as accepted, since it's reasonable to wait for further comments and/or answers.

Comment: I had a look at your other question. The answer by coffeemath is correct. There is a small gap in the other answer, which is that whether $g(x,z)=0$ or $h(-x,z)=0$ could depend on $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that implies conditional independence.

Write the conditional density and show that it factors into a product

\begin{eqnarray*}
  f \left( x, y|z \right) & = & \frac{f \left( x, y, z \right)}{f \left( z
  \right)}\\
  & \propto & \underbrace{g \left( x, z
  \right)}_{\text{depends only on }
  x} \times \underbrace{h \left( y, z
  \right)}_{\text{depends only on }
  y}\\
  & = & f \left( x|z \right) f \left( y|z \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Obviously the proportionality constant in the last equality is different from the one in the definition of the joint distribution (it could depend on z).

Comment: Thanks very much; it's very helpful! If you don't mind, I have [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330668/separate-expression-cx-y2-eyz) you may be able to solve too. Or guide me into which one is the correct answer (by voting the right one).